# In wordpress, how remove search widget from sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

$registered_sidebars = wp_get_sidebars_widgets(); get an output like this

```
Array
    (
         [sidebar] => Array
            (
                [0] => search-2
                [1] => recent-posts-2
                [2] => recent-comments-2
                [3] => archives-2
                [4] => categories-2
                [5] => meta-2
                [6] => advanced_sidebar_menu_category-2
                [7] => advanced_sidebar_menu-3
            )

    )
```

i want to remove search-2 from array, attempted like this

```
unregister_sidebar( 'search-2' );
```

but not works

Comment: simply go the `Appearance > Widgets` in wordpress backend and delete the search widget

Comment: only for search result page, required all other pages

Answer (score 3):

[unregister_sidebar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_sidebar) Unregisters sidebars, not sidebar widgets. 'search-2' is not a sidebar, rather a widget.

[wp_get_sidebars_widgets](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_sidebars_widgets) lists the active widgets. If you want to remove 'search-2' from the array returned by wp_get_sidebars_widgets simply go the Appearance > Widgets in the dashboard and "delete" the search widget from the sidebar.

**Edit:** To hide a widget on a specific page you can use a plugin like [Display Widgets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-widgets/), [Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/), or [Jetpack](http://jetpack.me/support/widget-visibility/).

Programmatic-ally, there are several options.

You can use either use different sidebars for different pages. You can include a specific sidebar using the [get_sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar).function on the template page. Just put in the alternate sidebar name.

You can also use the 'sidebars_widgets' filter.

```
add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'disable_search_widget' );

function disable_search_widget( $sidebars_widgets ) {

    if ( is_home() && is_array($sidebars_widgets['primary-widget-area']) ) {
            foreach($sidebars_widgets['primary-widget-area'] as $i => $widget) {
                if(strpos($widget, 'search-2') !== false) {
                    unset($sidebars_widgets['primary-widget-area'][$i]);
                }
            }

    }

    return $sidebars_widgets;
}
```

**Edit 2** Slight change to the code above. Should prevent error.

Comment: delete only for search result page, all other pages search-2 needed

Comment: getting error like Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Did you place it in your theme's functions.php file?

Comment: yah, copied into function.php, changed only is_home() to is_search()

Comment: I updated the script a bit to prevent errors, Do you get the same error when running it on is_home()?

Comment: Hello @YasirPoongadan, 
I come across the same problem. Did you get a solution ? 
I know it was long time ago...
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is great but if you are not convenient on using php, the easiest way actually is to use css and just hide the search widget :

```
.widget.widget_search{ display:none; }
```

So if you want to hide it on homepage only you can use something like this :

```
body.home .widget.widget_search{ display:none; }
```

Hope this would help you ;)

Cheers,
phpbits

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Deregister all widgets from sidebar. You have to call it once, for example in after_switch_theme action

```
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'deregister_sidebar_widgets');
function deregister_sidebar_widgets () {   
    $sidebar_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
    if (isset($sidebar_widgets['sidebar'])) {
       foreach($sidebar_widgets['sidebar'] as $i => $widget) {
           unset($sidebars_widgets['sidebar'][$i]);
        }
        wp_set_sidebars_widgets($sidebar_widgets);
    }
}
```